# svelte typescript error for $: syntax : Cannot use a declaration in a single-statement context

Tags: typescript, svelte

I am getting this error "Cannot use a declaration in a single-statement context" when using $: syntax in the script with lang="ts" in +page.svelte file. Also the in VCS: "'A label is not allowed here." is mentioned on the $

```
<script lang="ts">
    export let data;
    $: let payload = data.payload
</script>
```

$: syntax for reactivity is in the official documentation of svelte as should be working as intended with no errors

Comment: It is my bad. By removing `let`, it is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax *is* invalid. You cannot have a declaration keyword (`let`) there, it's just:

```js
$: payload = data.payload
```

Or, using destructuring:

```js
$: ({ payload } = data)
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're experiencing seems to be related to the TypeScript language service not recognizing Svelte's reactive $: syntax. This is not an issue with Svelte itself, but rather how your editor or IDE interprets Svelte syntax when TypeScript is enabled.

Possible Solutions:
Svelte TypeScript Plugin: If you're using VS Code, make sure you have the official Svelte for VS Code extension installed. This extension adds better TypeScript support for Svelte files.

Type Annotation: Sometimes adding type annotations can help the TypeScript compiler understand what you're trying to do, although this shouldn't be necessary for Svelte reactive statements.

```
    <script lang="ts">
    export let data: any;
    $: let payload: any = data.payload
</script>
```

Project Configuration: Ensure your tsconfig.json and (if you have one) svelte.config.js are set up correctly for TypeScript support.

Latest Packages: Make sure all your packages are up-to-date, especially the Svelte package and any TypeScript packages.

Restart Editor: Sometimes the language services get stuck and simply restarting your editor can fix the problem.

Check for Conflicts: Ensure that there are no conflicting extensions in your editor that might interfere with Svelte or TypeScript language features.

Ignore the Warning: If the code runs fine, this might be an editor issue that you can ignore. You might be able to suppress the warning in your editor settings.

Check Official Repositories for Issues: Sometimes these kinds of bugs are known issues that are either fixed in later versions or have workarounds suggested by the community. You can search in the GitHub repositories for the related packages.

Remember that Svelte's $: syntax is not standard TypeScript or JavaScript, so the TypeScript language service might not recognize it out of the box without a proper Svelte plugin for your editor.

Comment: Reactive statements are just [JS labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). They obey the same rules and are valid JS syntax, this has nothing to do with TS. You can try executing `$: let x = 1` and `$: x = 1` in a browser console or Node and see what happens.